# number of samples and Amplitude accuracy,what's the solution to this problem

Tags: fft, estimation, amplitude

I'm colleceting data samples from a device (temporal signal) in order to analyze it with FFT function in MATLAB R2015b,first i get N=4063 data points with (delta_t=0.000015s) so my frequency resolution is (delta_f=1/N*delta_t)=16.4Hz,this give me pretty good results with amplitude,but when i did another measurment with N=8192 data points (delta_t=0.000061)  to obtain better resolution,the amplitude is not correct,i don't know really how to deal with this issue.so please if any body can help me with this i will be grateful,thank you

ps:i'm new in signal processing

below my code in MATLAB

```
sig_2=asp_ach_de1;
Fs2 = 1/0.000061;      % Sampling frequency
T2 = 1/Fs2;            % Sampling period
L2 = 8192;             % Length of signal
t2 = (0:L2-1)*T2;      % Time vector
% FFT FUNCTION
Y2 = fft(sig_2(:,2))
Q2 = abs(Y2/L2);
Q1 = Q2(1:L2/2+1);
Q1(2:end-1) = 2*Q1(2:end-1);
f2 = Fs2*(0:(L2/2))/L2; %FREQUENCY
figure(3)
plot(f2,Q1)
```

[image: spectrum 8k Data pts]

Comment: Hiii! can you please also provide that **asp_ach_de1** signal? or do you want us to predict it ?

Comment: thank you Fat32,but how i'm suppose to share it with you here,it's 8192 line txt file or how to attach it.

Comment: here's the 2 signals asp_ach_de1 "4k and 8k", 
gist.github.com/bishopreb85/19b056cfbea0d8c10e7ff1d0fa389d00

Answer (score 1):

I think that what is happening to u is that the frequency which you are trying to measure is in between 2 of your FFT bins which will cause the power to spread between two different indexes of your result FFT.

Another possible solution , only if with higher resolution you are getting a lower value  , is that since as I understand this is a real signal with noise you may be summing more noise , on the first attempt, for each frequency of your FFT and as a result raising all the values of your FFT.

Without knowing the signal you are trying to process it is hard to know what is exactly the problem. also your FFT plots will help give a better answer.

Comment: Thank you shaiel cohen,it's a Vibration temporal signal,i'm suppose to get an amplitude between 25 and 35,so you see my amplitude is not correct.

Comment: Glad to help  if you could provide the file and the graph of the 4k samples and the code for your first plot ,  that would help provide an answer.

Comment: shaiel cohen,i tried to attach the file here but,i can't find any way to do it,so how you wanna from me to share with you the signal,can you suggest for me

Comment: Upload to a gist on git will probably be the most useful

Comment: I'm really sorry,i don't think that i understand you with "git" or how to use it,i have only a txt file if you want i'll send it to you,

Comment: Upload the file and post the link to it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com is for uploading small snippets of code Which is useful for this sort of thing

Comment: Thank you,shaiel cohen,i will upload it and informe you but,i think now i have some issues to access to gist.github.com ,"network restriction",i'll try after,thank you ,i really appreciate your help

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bishopreb85/19b056cfbea0d8c10e7ff1d0fa389d00

Comment: If I understood your file right it is a tab delimated value. U are calculating the fft on the second collumn. I implemented your code in qpython and got the expected result so I am going to say that the error is probably in the part beforehand which is the parsing of the file.

Comment: i calculated the second column of course,you see if you use the same code i give it with the question you will find max amplitude at 1954Hz ,with a vibration analyser this amplitude is at (1916Hz 4Hz resolution ) rather than 1954Hz ,so there's something missing for sure with my code,the form of spectrum in generale almost the same so FFT should be correct,so what you say shaiel cohen

Comment: Two possible solutions , a. The device has some max diff ( which doesn't equal to the resolution! ) ,B your actual sampling rate is not exactly what is specified. Slower sample rate will mean lower frequencies for the FFT.

Comment: I am actually very positive about the practical sample rate being lower since solutions with changing sample rate tend to have round sample rates and the divide them by a number now since you pointed out that you sampled the first with $T_{s1} = 0.000015$ and then with $T_{s2} = 0.000061 = 4*0.00001525$ now if you correct for that you do get that the max is at 1920  !

Comment: Indeed,shaiel cohen,i tryed it with 0.00001525 and i get 1920 i was going to tell you about it,the same point for me too 1920 Hz but the amplitude is decreasing a little bit about 18 ,infact even the device has a leakage error,when i try to measure with 2 Hz and 4 Hz the amplitude increase with 4 Hz.now i'm thinking about applying the FFT per parts ,i will divide the signal and apply the FFT to each part,what you think shaiel cohen....by the way i enjoyed this discussion with you...thank you

Comment: Glad to help,  for the FFT per part you should use the spectrogram function.